# jxl set font to date type cell

Tags: java, excel, jxl, jexcelapi

I'm using jxl to create excel files. I need to set a particular font for date type cells. When I write a text cell it's easy to do:

```
WritableFont arial10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 10);
    arial = new WritableCellFormat(arial10pt);
```

But when I create a date cell, using the following code, I don't know how to set a font:

```
DateFormat customDateFormat = new DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    WritableCellFormat dateFormat = new WritableCellFormat(customDateFormat);
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but worth an answer should anyone else get here in search of this info:

```
WritableFont arial10pt = new WritableFont(WritableFont.ARIAL, 10);
arial = new WritableCellFormat(arial10pt);
DateFormat customDateFormat = new DateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
WritableCellFormat dateFormat = new WritableCellFormat(arial10pt,customDateFormat);
```

Comment: I found this useful. :D